# Erlang many-to-many list rebuilding

Tags: list, erlang

I need parse many-many relation.

I have list like:

```
[
 {item1, [rel1, rel2, rel3]},
 {item2, [rel2, rel5]},
 {item3, [rel1, rel4]}, 
 ...
]

I need to build new list like:
[
 {rel1, [item1, item3]},
 {rel2, [item1, item2]},
 ...
]
```

How can I do it efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

Most efficient way using dict:

```
F = fun({Item,Rels}, Dict) ->
  H = fun(L) -> [Item|L] end,
  G = fun(Rel, D) -> dict:update(Rel, H, [Item], D) end,
  lists:foldl(G, Dict, Rels)
end,
dict:to_list(lists:foldl(F, dict:new(), Input)).
```

Using ets can be faster for really big data due less GC pressure:

```
Tab = ets:new(ok, [private]),
[ ets:insert(Tab,
  {Rel, case ets:lookup(Tab, Rel) of
      [] -> [Item];
      [{_, L}] -> [Item|L]
    end})
  || {Item, Rels} <- Input, Rel <- Rels ],
Result = ets:tab2list(Tab),
ets:delete(Tab),
Result.
```

**Edit**:
Since R17 there are maps and since R18 they should be efficient even for big amount of keys so now there is more efficient version using maps:

```
F = fun({Item, Rels}, Map) ->
  G = fun(Rel, M) -> maps:put(Rel, [Item|maps:get(Rel, M, [])], M) end,
  lists:foldl(G, Map, Rels)
end,
maps:to_list(lists:foldl(F, #{}, L)).
```

Answer (score 1):

```
D = dict:from_list(INPUT),
F = fun(K,V,ACC) ->
        dict:update(V, fun(X) -> [K|X] end, [X], ACC)
    end
D2 = dict:fold(F, dict:new(), D),
OUTPUT = dict:to_list(D2).
```

Answer (score 1):

```
convert_relation(Relations) ->  
    Dict = 
        lists:foldl(fun({Item, RelList}, Dict1) ->
                            lists:foldl(fun(Rel, Dict2) ->
                                                dict:append(Rel, Item, Dict2)
                                        end, Dict1, RelList)
                    end, dict:new(), Relations),
    dict:to_list(Dict).
```